# Grep specific IP addresses

Tags: regex, grep

I have an IP address, say `192.168.1.1`, that I want to match.

I have a file called `afile` that looks like this

```
 item1, item2, 192.168.1.1
 item3, item4, 192.168.1.10
 item5, item6, 192.168.2.1
```

If I do `grep "192.168.1.1" afile` both the first and second lines of `afile` are matched, which is not what I want.

I'm aware of plenty of regular expressions that will match any IP address, but I'm not aware of any regular expressions that match a particular IP address.

Any help with this is appreciated.

What if the IP address isn't on the end of the line? For example, what if columns two and three were swapped in my example file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add a `$` to the end of the regex, to make it match the end of the line. I would also suggest escaping the dots, as a `.` in a regex means "match any character". So your regex would become:

```
grep "192\.168\.1\.1$" afile
```

Comment: It looks like you answered first.

Answer (score 1):

You want to match end of line after the last one. Try this :

```
grep "192.168.1.1$"
```

Answer (score 1):

`grep` is an abbreviated version of `g/re/p` where "re" is a regular expression.  In RegEx, a period means "Any character".  To make it a literal period, escape it with a backslash.

```
grep "192\.168\.1\.1$" afile
```

As others said, you also need to say it ends the line.

Comment: I don't need to escape the periods since the expression is in quotes.  `"192.168.1.1"` works just as well as `192\.168\.1\.1`

Comment: @devin, I checked just to be sure.  If you don't escape them, your pattern will match *"item1, item2, **192T168Q1]1**"*, quotes or not.

Answer (score 0):

this is what you want:

```
grep "192.168.1.1\s" afile
```

Comment: You should use `\b` instead of `\s`. Otherwise it won't match at the end of the file.

Comment: Please consider adding at least some explanation as though why this answer the question